# Creating a new ACO using the CakePHP console?

Tags: cakephp, acl

I created a root ACO with the following command:

```
cake acl create aco root controllers
```

This is all well and fine, but how would I create a new entry for **Users::index()**? I'm asking this because I created an "administrator" group and granted it all permissions to the **controllers** ACO but when I login as the admin I still get that I don't have permission.

So maybe I need to actually create an ACO for the action to view it... So, anyone knows how to add a new Aco for **Controller::action()?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would add a new Aco Controller::action via

```
cake acl create aco controllers Users
```

then

```
cake acl create aco Users index
```

If you have granted permissions via the console to controllers and you have created ACO's for them you should have full access? Have you set up your User and Group models correctly using parentNode() and bindNode() as defined here http://book.cakephp.org/view/1547/Acts-As-a-Requester